How to apply filter on trace for all except specific procedure
I want to enable traces on sql server for all calls over 100ms in duration. But for some procedure, lets call it proc1 I want to catch it all the time, ignoring this filter. How I can do it? Currently the below filter applies on all procedures:
SET @bigintfilter = 100000; -- 100 in ms
EXECUTE sp_trace_setfilter @TraceID, 13, @FilterforR, 4, @bigintfilter; -- Duration greater or equal to
